# JQUERY first element after every button

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

```
<button> Show </button>
<ol style="display:none;">
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <li>
        <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>">
                <?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
                <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span>
                <?php echo $_item->getLabel(); ?>
                <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                    <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

I have following code this prints filters in magento I want to show/hide filters. This prints many times button -> ol of filters button -> ol from filters. I want to make this: When i click on button I want only first ol after button to show or hide. I need help thanks!

Comment: Remove `php` code and only write html result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** method to select immediate following sibling

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this)
    .next() // get immediately next sibling
    .toggle(); // toggle the visible states
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Show</button>
<ol style="display:none;">
  <li>list
    <li>
</ol>
<button>Show</button>
<ol style="display:none;">
  <li>list
    <li>
</ol>
<button>Show</button>
<ol style="display:none;">
  <li>list
    <li>
</ol>
<button>Show</button>
<ol style="display:none;">
  <li>list
    <li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, This work but how i can also hide after 2nd click.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to using jQuery next() You can also wrap Button and Ol pairs by Div tags. That way when will need add some markup between Button and Ol JS code will still work.

```
<div class="filters-box">
    <button>...</button>
    <ol>...</ol>
</div>
```

Then add click event like this:

```
$('.filters-box button').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this),
        $box = $button.parent(),
        $options = $box.find('ol');

    $options.toggle();
});
```

A little bit more code but it is more elastic to extend in need. Such wrapper can also be handy for positioning elements. It is a matter of case to not make infamous "divits" out of this.